# Adding children recursively to tree structure (children before parent)

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I'm doing an assignment for an internship, and they gave me a task to create a navigation menu, such as this one down bellow:

```
. Company
.... About Us
....... Team
.... Mission
. References
.... Client 1
.... Client 2
```

The whole point of the task is for me to find a way to transform this input into a tree structure and then print it out recursively...
The input is:

```
ID NAME PARENTID
1; Company; NULL;
2; About Us; 1;
3; Mission; 1;
4; Team; 2;
5; Client1; 7;
6; Client2; 7;
7; References; NULL;
```

If this was a first parent then children type of input, then the task would be super easy, however I'm stuck and can't seem to understand the algorithm behind it. The whole deal is that References are added at the end, but Client 1 & Client 2 are both children of References...

Here are the codes:

Model class:

```
// WITH SETTERS AND GETTERS
public class NavLink
{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String parentId;
    private String isHidden;
    private String linkUrl;
}
```

Triple Linked List Node Class:

```
public class TLLNode<NavLink>
{
    public NavLink element;
    public TLLNode<NavLink> parent, sibling, child;

    public TLLNode(NavLink elem)
    {
        this.element = elem;
        parent = sibling = child = null;
    }
}
```

Tree class:

```
public class Tree
{
    private TLLNode<NavLink> root;

    public Tree(NavLink element) { this.root = new TLLNode(element); }

    public TLLNode<NavLink> getRoot() { return this.root; }

    public void addChild(TLLNode<NavLink> node, NavLink element)
    {
        TLLNode<NavLink> insert =  new TLLNode<>(element);

       if (node.child == null)
            node.child = insert;

       else
       {
            if (node.child.element.getName().compareTo(insert.element.getName()) > 0)
                    insert.sibling = node.child;
            else
            {
                TLLNode<NavLink> tmp = node.child;
                while (tmp.sibling != null)
                {
                    if (tmp.sibling.element.getName().compareTo(insert.element.getName()) > 0)
                    {
                        insert.sibling = tmp.sibling;
                        break;
                    }
                    tmp = tmp.sibling;
                }
                tmp.sibling = insert;
            }
        }
        insert.parent = node;
    }

    public void printTree() { printTreeRecursive(this.root, 0); }

    private void printTreeRecursive(TLLNode<NavLink> node, int level)
    {
        if (node == null)
            return;

        for (int i=0; i < level-1; i++)
            System.out.print("...");

        if (node.element.getHidden().equalsIgnoreCase("False"))
            System.out.println("." + node.element.getName());

        TLLNode<NavLink> tmp = node.child;
        while (tmp != null)
        {
            printTreeRecursive(tmp, level+1);
            tmp = tmp.sibling;
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the Main class, where the problem is situated:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        String[] parts;
        List<NavLink> list = new LinkedList<>();

        NavLink link = new NavLink("NULL", "/", "/", "True", "/" );
        Tree tree = new Tree(link);

        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            parts = br.readLine().split(";");
            link = new NavLink(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3], parts[4]);

            list.add(link);
        }

        /*TLLNode<NavLink> current;
        for (NavLink item : links)
        {
            current = new TLLNode<>(item);
            System.out.println(item);
            for (NavLink tmp : links.subList(1, links.size()))
            {
                if (tmp.getParentId().equalsIgnoreCase(current.element.getId()))
                    tree.addChild(current, tmp);
            }
        }*/

        addChildRecursive(tree, list, tree.getRoot());
        tree.printTree();
    }

    public static void addChildRecursive(Tree tree, List<NavLink> list, TLLNode<NavLink> current)
    {
        if (current == null)
            return;

        TLLNode<NavLink> insert;
        for (NavLink item : list)
        {
            insert = new TLLNode<>(item);
            if (insert.element.getParentId() == current.element.getId())
            {
                tree.addChild(current, insert.element);
                list.remove(insert.element);
                addChildRecursive(tree, list, current.child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The method `addChildRecursive` is the one that is giving me the problems, in the output it doesn't say that there are any errors.

I don't understand what needs to be done here?

P.S. Ignore the isHidden and other attributes, the main problem is with the `addChildRecursive` method

Answer (score 1):

First of all in java it's recommended that you check if two strings are equal with now equals() function and not the == operator.
Now for your question, it's seems that you only check the child of the current node and because there could be more than one child you don't check them all.
I suggest to use a list of child or some other sort of mechanism to save all the children directly and not thru the "sibling" pointer.